# How to set user-agent in python-webkit

Tags: python, webkit

```
import webkit
import gtk
import jswebkit

webview = webkit.WebView()
webview.connect('load-finished', lambda v, f: gtk.main_quit())
# How can I set user-agent ?
webview.load_uri('http://localhost/tech/test.html')
gtk.main()
js = jswebkit.JSContext(webview.get_main_frame().get_global_context())
renderedBody = str(js.EvaluateScript('document.body.innerHTML'))
print renderedBody
```

I want set user-agent like "iPad" or other for webkit.WebView, How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
  settings = webkit.WebSettings()
  settings.set_property('user-agent', 'iPad')
  webview.set_settings(settings)
```